# C/C++ : A weird library function declaration

Tags: c++, c, function

I found this kind of functions declarations in a C/C++ Library and I wonder if it about any standard to declare a function at this way...

```
SOMELIBAPI( someReturnType, someLibFuncName, (int arg1, int arg2));
```

Thank you for any information you can give me!

Comment: It's just a macro...

Comment: Really? Because there is also the definition of the function using the same way: SOMELIBAPI( someReturnType, someLibFuncName, (int arg1, int arg2)){....}

Comment: And? Function declarations and definitions are allowed to differ only by a ; or {…}

Comment: There is no such thing as "a C/C++ library". Which language are you using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That may in fact explain the macro, it's quite possible that the macro hides a `extern "C"` when compiling as C++.

Comment: @Julia Did you find an answer to your question? If so, you should consider marking the answer that best fit you as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This probably expands conditionally to either

```
__declspec(dllexport) someReturnType someLibFuncName (int arg1, int arg2)
```

or

```
__declspec(dllimport) someReturnType someLibFuncName (int arg1, int arg2).
```

The reason for this is that it allows you to use the same header both in the DLL and in the client application. Doing it this way is also [suggested by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx).

This leaves the question open though, why a function-like macro was used instead of a simpler "normal" macro.

Answer (score 0):

They are using macros to create the function declaration, possibly something like

```
#define SOMELIBAP(a, b, c) extern "C" a b c ;
```